# How do we plot nonlinear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-optimization, mathematical-modeling, nonlinear-system

If this is not nonlinear I apologize, I'm still learning differential equations. I am attempting to make a stream plot of a predator-prey model of eccentric closed curves by using the following commands and then find the period of oscillation max min number of population etc. and when plotting the oscillatory plot they are out of phase.
I also tried making the constants below arbitrary and then attempting to plot this just creates more issues

```
 deq1 = x'[t] == 0.01*7*x[t] - 0.0001*4*x[t]*y[t];
 deq2 = y'[t] == -0.01*8*y[t] + 0.0001*5*x[t]*y[t];
 StreamPlot[{deq1, deq2}, {x, -0.1, 600}, {y, -0.1, 600}]
```

I have successfully created a single ParametricPlot using to result in a single eccentric closed curve

```
  solution = NDSolve[{deq1, deq2, x[0] == 600, y[0] == 100}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 500}]
  ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. solution], {t, 0, 400}]
```

Comment: Lotka-Volterra predator-prey solutions **are** out of phase. What is your question?

Comment: My question is how would I plot the general stream plot for this model.... I have attempted the above as stated but this does not work and as far as I understand how stream plots work it should? I am a little confused if the method for plotting this would vary any as it is out of phase and nonlinear?

Comment: How the plotting method should depend on it being out of phase or nonlinear escapes me, I must admit. For streamplots, simply use `streamplot[{0.01*7*x - 0.0001*4*x*y,-0.01*8*y + 0.0001*5*x*y},{x, -0.1, 600}, {y, -0.1, 600}]`.

Comment: Right, I didn't think it would either which is why I was confused as to why this did not work and I tried what you suggested nad it now works thank you. Must have been a problem with the [t] or assignments possibly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in a comment, typing [there](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) the line

`streamplot[{0.01*7*x - 0.0001*4*x*y,-0.01*8*y + 0.0001*5*x*y},{x, -0.1, 600}, {y, -0.1, 600}]`

produces

[image]

Lazy people would rather type the line

`streamplot[{7x - 4xy,-8y + 5xy},{x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 6}]`

which, for good reasons, produces the same diagram, only rescaled:

[image]